# Printing group name and corresponding data from text

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I have written a regex pattern for my data with the help of [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/).

```
regex=r"(?P<tag_name>\w+), {(('\w+': '(\w+|\w+-\d)')?,?\s?('\w+': '(\w+|\d.\d{1,})')?)?}, (?P<text>[\w .,]+)"
```

The data is of the following type in `sample.txt`:

```
tag1, {'id': 'line_1', 'Prob': '0.96'}, None 
tag2, {'a_id': 'aid'}, None 
tag3, {}, John 
x, {},   
tag3, {}, Doe
```

Now I want the desired output to be stored in a text file in following manner:

```
    Line_number: line_1
    <group_name_tag1>: None
    <group_name_tag3>: John
    <group_name_tagx>: 
    <group_name_tag3>: Doe
```

I have tried following

```
import re
regex=r"(?P<tag_name>\w+)?,\s({('id':\s'(?P<Line_Number>\w+)',\s'Prob':\s'(\d.\d{1,}|\w+)')?},)?([\w .]+)"
temp=[]
with open("sample.txt", "r") as ins:

    for line in ins:
        temp.append(re.findall(regex, line, re.I))
```

But don't get desired output

Comment: Why is `<group_name_tag2>: None` not in output?

Comment: `{'a_id': 'aid'}` is not useful.

Comment: If it makes easy we can use it I can manually delete it

Comment: You may use this regex: https://regex101.com/r/aFBwtU/1